# LINQ / EF Core cannot use string.Contains in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my opinion this should be pretty straight forward:
I have a list of strings and I want to return only the db rows, where the column matches **all of the strings** contained in the list.

so for instance, if my string search query is `{ "R", "E", "I" }` it should return all records that contain the letters R, E and I in the column MyStringColumn (in any order).

Code Example:

```
var reiks = new List<string> { "R", "E", "I" };
var result = _context.MyTable.Where(x => reiks.All(r => x.MyStringColumn.Contains(r)));
```

Unfortunately, this returns the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException. The LINQ expression
> 'DbSet()
> .Where(c => __reiks_0
> .All(r => c.MyStringColumn.Contains(r)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

If I rewrite the code like this it works, but this is only a temporary solution, as I cannot guarantee that there will only be 3 strings:

```
var result = _context.MyTable.Where(x => ((reiks.Count == 0 || x.MyStringColumn.Contains(reiks[0])) && (reiks.Count <= 1 || x.MyStringColumn.Contains(reiks[1])) && (reiks.Count <= 2 || x.MyStringColumn.Contains(reiks[2]))));
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried the first code example with Any instead of `All`, but it didn't work either way.

Comment: It is because the `All` doesn't have a match with any SQL Clause so EF can't generate the SQL for you.

Comment: @CodeNotFound What would be an alternative way to translate this code? and shouldn't it have worked with Any()?

Comment: The Alternative is to create a stored procedure that will receive the reiks list as a parameter and map the result to your entity. It is way more performant that sending a big query to your database server.

Comment: @TimGerhard Think about what the equivalent SQL for that query would be and if you still think the translator should be able to do that. Maybe structuring an equivalent SQL query will give you a different Linq equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

You can break down the condition like :

```cs
var reiks = new List<string> { "R", "E", "I" };
var query = _context.MyTable.AsQueryable();
foreach(var reik in reiks)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.MyStringColumn.Contains(reik));
}
var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Try this:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation)

```
var result = _context.MyTable.AsEnumerable()
                             .Where(x => reiks.All(r => x.MyStringColumn.Contains(r)));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).